# How to install VS Build Tools 2022 with some custom install choices using chocolatey non interactively?

Tags: visual-studio, chocolatey

I want to install VS Build Tool 2022 with the following components:

1. .NET Desktop Build Tools

   - Exclude .Net Framework 4.8 targeting pack
2. Web development Build Tools
3. Node.js Build Tools

   - Include optional

I do not know currently how to exclude the .Net Framework 4.8 targeting pack, but I thought I understood how to do the rest and here is the script I created based on the information in https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2022buildtools-preview:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

$Components = @(
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NodeBuildTools;includeOptional",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools"
)

$InstallerArgs = "--add " + ($Components -join " --add ")

choco install visualstudio2022buildtools -y $InstallerArgs
```

Unfortunately, it only installs the bare minimum. The rest I have to do manually through the VS Installer.

So my script must be wrong, but where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass the arguments down to the vs_buildtools.exe installer you need to include the `--params` option.

```
choco install visualstudio2022buildtools -y --params $InstallerArgs
```

Comment: Maybe you can help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73072353/how-to-install-vs-build-tools-2022-without-net-4-8-targeting-pack-using-choco ?