# How to install VS Build Tools 2022 without ".NET 4.8 targeting pack" using chocolatey non interactively?

Tags: visual-studio

This question is related to [How to install VS Build Tools 2022 with some custom install choices using chocolatey non interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73069481/how-to-install-vs-build-tools-2022-with-some-custom-install-choices-using-chocol)

How can I instruct the VS installer NOT to install the .NET 4.8 targeting pack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like how the `--add` parameter can add Workloads or specific Component IDs, the `--remove` can do the opposite.

`vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --remove Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack`

You cannot remove required dependencies. Only recommended and optional (if you included the `;includeRecommeded` or `;includeOptional` with the workload ID).

You can read all about the vs_installer CLI [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).
An overview of the workloads [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-and-component-ids?view=vs-2022). Or specifically the [Build Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2022&preserve-view=true) workloads.

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly - in case of 4.8 .NET targeting pack, removing it in VS Installer also removes its dependency - .Net 4.8 Development SDK and I am fine with that. Will it work the same when I add `--remove Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack` ?